# Submit button on page will not react to .click() command using Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, jsf, selenium-chromedriver

We have two different pages with submit button on each. On one page submit button register the click and test continue. On second page you can see that Selenium clicked on button, but button won't register the click and test will fail.
Working button:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <button id="form2:btnContinue" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-right fr" type="submit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:"form2:btnContinue",u:"form1 form2 form3 form2:btnContinue"});return false;" name="form2:btnContinue" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-right ui-icon ui-c fa fa-caret-right"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Continue</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Nonworking button:

```
<div class="clearfix ">
<button id="form:j_idt210" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only fr" type="submit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:"form:j_idt210",u:"form form2 confirmationPanel"});return false;" name="form:j_idt210" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Submit Payment</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I declare both Webelements similarly. Working button:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='form2:btnContinue']")
    private WebElement processPaymentButton;
```

Nonworking button:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='form:j_idt210']")
    private WebElement submitFormButton;
```

Also PageObjects looks completely same. Working button:

```
public void setProcessPayment() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 9);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(processPaymentButton));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(processPaymentButton));

        processPaymentButton.click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(verificationInputField));

        sendKeysElement(verificationInputField, "1111");
        sendPaymentButton.click();
    }
```

Nonworking button:

```
public void setProcessPayment() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 9);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(submitFormButton));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(submitFormButton));

        submitFormButton.click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(authorizationTokenField));

        sendKeysElement(authorizationTokenField, "1111");
        authorizePaymentButton.click();
    }
```

I tried change *.click()* with .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER), script or Action. Basically I tried everything I was able to found. I also change way button is accessed (CSS, ID, different Xpath approaches). Nothing is working, however when you watch running test, you can clearly see, that Selenium clicked the button. Button was working with Selenium while ago, but than it stopped.

We are using Selenium 2.47.1 and latest ChromeDriver. Button is working when you click on it manually.
Thank you for your help.

NOTE: Issue is more related to button itself than the Selenium. If you give us hint how to fix button to work, we will be thankful.

Comment: Does it work if you click manually?

Comment: Have you tried checking if the button is visible/enabled before clicking it?

Comment: I updated my question. Yes, it is possible to click on button manually and it works. I'm also checking if it's visible and clickable. I can try if it's enabled (there should not be anything to disable it however), how I can check if it is enabled?

Comment: Element is enabled. 
_assertEquals(true, submitFormButton.isEnabled());_

Answer (score 0):

Solution to whole problem lays with "Bank Code" component above. This component contains auto-filler which will display table with possible results (different bank codes and canal used for transaction).

Whole issue was in code I was sending to this component, I was sending bank code with channel, which caused Java on component to break, preventing button to be functional. I found this trying my test with Selenium IDE. Now its working. 

So lesson learned from this whole issue is that each component on page can interfere with each other and your button can work if you just adjust your test.